ASP.NET MVC : trouble with SQL token distributed serialization - Microsoft Graph SDK - identity web
As the title says, I have an ASP.NET MVC app running on .NET 4.7.2 to which I want to integrate Microsoft 365 functionalities. For this, I have already registered the app in Microsoft Entra ID.
I can instantiate the Graph client in the HomeController like this:
var graphClient = this.GetGraphServiceClient();

From which I can hit the different endpoints I need without any problems.
var canales = await graphClient.Teams[XxTeam.Id]
                               .Channels
                               .GetAsync();

This is my configuration, notice I chose distributed token serialization with SQL Server.
Startup.cs:
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    try
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);                
 
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
 
        OwinTokenAcquirerFactory factory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance<OwinTokenAcquirerFactory>();                             
 
        app.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(factory);                
 
        factory.Services
               .Configure<ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions>(options => { })
               .AddMicrosoftGraph()
               .AddDistributedTokenCaches()
               .Configure<MsalDistributedTokenCacheAdapterOptions>(options =>
                    {
                        options.DisableL1Cache = false;
                    })
               .AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
                    {
                        options.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=...; Integrated Security=True;";
                        options.SchemaName = "dbo";
                        options.TableName = "TestCache";
                    });                
 
        factory.Build();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

This worked a couple of times, I had tokens inserted in the suggested table (docs) when all of a sudden, it didn't anymore. Tokens are no longer been inserted in the selected database anymore.
I don't understand how can I debug this in a way to be able to detect if I'm making any mistake with the connection string (which I doubt) or if I'm getting any exception.
I tried changing my connection strings in different ways, no luck so far.
